# Angular CLI - change folder for source code

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I want to start new Angular 5 project, but I need that my code will be in another folder than configuration files. Is possible to do that in cli commands?

For example here is my folder structure:

```
-/root
-/src/main/java
-/pom.xml
```

After generation Angular 5 project I need that, configuration files will be in root and source codes in **src/main/webapp** like that:

```
-/root
-/src/main/java
-/src/main/webapp
-/src/main/webapp/app
-/src/main/webapp/index.html
-/src/main/webapp/...
-/pom.xml
-/.angular-cli.json
-/package.json
-/...
```

Is it possible? If yes how? Thanks.

Comment: i dont think its possible as angular cli is made for generating new project easily and taking care of best practices using angular. And your folder structure is definitly not following best practices.

Comment: @maerlin I saw that structure in jhipster ... so I thought it's fine.

Comment: Did you take a look into http://www.jhipster.tech/using-angular/ ? the structure looks different than yours - and they have a chapter about angular-cli, like the generation of components and their custom angular-cli config. seems to me you mixed up your java project files with with angular project files, instead of having them separated.

Comment: @maerlin yes this is what I mean ... index.html, components, content and other code in .../webapp and configuration like package.json, cli setting, and such stuff in root like pom file.

Comment: Why is this down voted?

Answer (score 5):

I'm your `angular-cli.json` file, you have an option called `root` that is used for specifying the directory of your apps root folder, relative to your configuration file.

You could for example put, a path like this, which might fit your need:

```
"root": "src/main/webapp/app",
```

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli